# Struggling creating a median routine in SQL

Tags: java, sql, google-bigquery

I'm tring to create a function that calculate the median in a SQL BigQuery database.

It is part of a creation of a new table on the dataset.

The problem is that sometime the group has only one value and SQL give it to the function as a FLOAT type, meanwhile the others sent it as an array.

I'm working on a Legacy SQL BigQuery server with DBeaver.

I find SQL quite tricky and I'm stuck from few hours. Thanks

This code works but only with arrays:

```
CREATE FUNCTION median(x ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  x.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  var half = Math.floor(x.length / 2);
  if (x.length % 2 == 0) {
    return (x[half - 1] + x[half]) / 2.0;
  } else {
    return x[half];
  }
""";
```

Thi one return this error: `Errore SQL [100032] [HY000]: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Templated js UDFs are not yet supported, but function median has a templated parameter`

```
CREATE FUNCTION median(x ANY TYPE)
RETURNS NUMERIC
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  var arr = Array.isArray(x) ? x : [x];
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  var half = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
    return (arr[half - 1] + arr[half]) / 2.0;
  } else {
    return arr[half];
  }
""";
```

Comment: The docs rule out overloading using polymorphic functions: "Each dataset can only contain one persistent UDF with the same name."  While I'm not crazy about the performance implications, you could cheat it by passing `TO_JSON_STRING(t)`.

Comment: Would `PERCENTILE_CONT(order_value, 0.5)` work for your use case?

Comment: @phatfingers , the PERCENTILE_CONT() return the error: `Errore SQL [100032] [HY000]: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: percentile_cont aggregate function is not supported.`
I'm gonna read the doc about TO_JSON_STRING() and I'll try to implement it

Answer (score 0):

There is an UDF to obtain the median. Because it does work with SQL, there is no need for JavaScript and therefore any input type of array will work.

```sql
SELECT `bigquery-public-data.persistent_udfs.median`([1,2,5,7]);
```

However, this query only work in the us zone.

Otherwise please take the code of this query and put it in a tempory udf; This would be the query then:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
(
  SELECT IF (
    MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
    (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2,
    arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]
  )
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
)
);
select median([5,7,9,1])
```

Comment: The US funtion works, but unfortunately I'm not in the US. Is it possible to 'import it in may dataset?
Regarding the other option, firstly I would like to thank you, but I still got this error: `[Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Invalid function L1_POLIMI.median
Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type FLOAT64
Analysis of function Templated_SQL_Function:median failed at [9:29]`

Comment: Import in your dataset: `CREATE  FUNCTION YOURDATASET.median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (`   The function excepts an array not a single value.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that sometimes the group is a single value, not an array, maybe I wasn't clear but that is my problem.

Comment: BigQuery UDF cannot handle polymorph functions. An array functions expects an array not a scala value. As you call the UDF-function in any query, you know that the argument is a single value or an array. Thus you can choose the right function. The only way  to let BigQuery handle any format is to convert it to text with `TO_JSON_STRING(t)` and parse this text with JavaScript in an UDF.